# Exact difference between AOT and IVY?

Tags: typescript, compiler-optimization, angular9

**After searching about Ivy and AOT I am confused, who is really compile the code?**

Comment: Please check the angular official website https://angular.io/guide/ivy  . AOT & JIT diffrence https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/

Answer (score 28):

1. **Angular Ivy** is the new default **rendering engine**.
2. Starting from version 9 of Angular, your TypeScript code will be compiled using **Ivy** instead of the older **ViewEngine** (VE).
3. Basically, **Ivy** decreases your **bundle sizes, enhances testing, and improves debugging capabilities**. In addition, **Ivy uses Ahead-of-Time compilation** to speed up your apps.

To summarise -

```
+---------------------------+-------------------+
| Ivy                       | AOT               |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
| It is a rendering engine. | It is a compiler. |
+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

Real difference would be between -

1. Ivy vs ViewEngine(VE)
2. AOT vs JIT